# custom keyboard layout not active after reboot

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have customized my keyboard layout by changing a line in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/da` (so my onehalf key is now a dollar - easier when coding in PHP).

My problem is that this change is not remembered by Ubuntu when I reboot - the file is not changed, but the key is now onehalf again.
If I go into "Keyboard Layout" in the system settings and then add a random language and remove it again, my own layout is back again.

Is there some sort of cache that I need to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It were a cache issue.

I fixed the issue by removing the xkm files in `/var/lib/xkm`.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm
```

And then rebooting (I'm not sure how to regenerate the cache files without doing so).

Comment: A cleaner way would be `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data` since you don't mess with automatically generated files.